# winsock asynchronous receive in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, winsock

currently wsock.dll is used in Excel 2007 to connect to a TCP server. It is fine that I can send something out. However, regarding receiving, is there any way to make it event driven as I don't know when there is a msg sending to the Excel? And recv call will be blocked until something is arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your hands on the Winsock ActiveX control then [you can used an event-based programming model](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163999). I've excerpted this example for Access:

```
Private Sub axWinsockServer_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strClientMsg As String

    ' The DataArrival event fires on the server when the client sends
    ' information. Get the data and display it in a text box.
    wsServer.GetData strClientMsg, vbString
    Me!Text1.Value = strClientMsg
End Sub
```

Although consider why, exactly, you need a spreadsheet to do network communication.

Comment: may I know winsock activex is free to download or not?

Comment: As far as I know it's free but extremely old. It's first party (i.e. Microsoft).

Comment: ok thanks. BTW do you know if there is a good non-free winsock activex control? I found one called alt winsock activex. However, it can only send ascii not binary data